# Cantor Function and Integral of a Indicator Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cantor-set

So I stumbled over following definition of the Cantor Function $f_n$:
Let $$g_n(x) := \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{x \in C_n\}}(x)$$
Where $C_n$ is the n-th Cantor Set.
Then $f_n$ is defined as: $$f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}g_n(t)dt$$
This is a beautiful definition (if you know how to integrate this), since it follows that $f_n$ is continous and increasing. 
But how do I integrate this?
I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\unicode{x1D7D9}_{\{x \in A\}}(x)dx = \int_{A}dx$. But that does not help me since we are integrating to $x$ and not $1$.

EDIT:
I believe the following is correct:
 $$f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}g_n(t)dt = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n length(C_n\backslash(x, 1])$$
where $(1, 1] = \emptyset$.

Comment: Your remark after EDIT is correct. Equivalently, $f_n(x) = \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \operatorname{length}(C_n \cap [0,x])$.

Comment: Regarding how to integrate $g_n$, drawing a picture helps. Start with $g_1$. This is the characteristic function of $[0,1/3] \cup [2/3, 1]$. When we integrate $g_1$ from $0$ to $x$, the result increases linearly on $[0,1/3]$ and $[2/3, 1]$ since $g_n$ is constant and nonzero on these intervals, and it is constant on $[1/3, 2/3]$ since $g_1$ is zero on the latter interval. Finally, note that the $(3/2)^n$ scale factor results in $f_n(1) = 1$, since the measure of $C_n$ is $(2/3)^n$.

Comment: Similarly, for an arbitrary $n$, the set $C_n$ is the disjoint union of $2^n$ intervals, each of length $(1/3)^n$. The integral of $g_n$ will be linear and increasing over each of these intervals, and constant everywhere else. The slope of $f_n$ on each of the intervals will be $(3/2)^n$. So, as $n$ increases, $f_n$ is constant over larger and larger portions of $[0,1]$, and does all of its climbing (with increasingly higher slope) on $C_n$. In the limit, you get a function which is constant everywhere except on the Cantor set, and it climbs from 0 to 1 on a set of measure zero!

Comment: @Bungo Can you at least provide the solution to the "limiting" function? I am stuck on how one can justify this.

Comment: @BrazyOski - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cantor function is the limit of this seqence of functions $f_n$. So the nice properties you cite don't follow from this definition without a little extra argument. The "n-th Cantor set" you refer to is the n-th stage in the construction of the cantor ternary set. The integral is just the total length of the support of the nth stage up to the point $x$. In other words this is a pretty tame function and integration is straightforward.

For a picture see the "iterative construction" on the Wikipedia page. $f_n$ is the nth stage of this construction. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: so my EDIT is correct?

Comment: Yes but I wasn't sure you understood that the cantor function was a limit of these and that the pieces were simple (since otherwise why there would be a question of how to integrate such a thing?) Note that the fact it is a limit makes the fact that it is continuous not follow completely trivially from this definition.

Comment: I know that the Cantor function is the limit. But I mean that all $f_n$ are continuous and that follows because $f_n$ is a Riemann integral, doesnt it?

Comment: @Chiray In general, the limit of a sequence of continuous functions need not be continuous. But the limit **will** be continuous if the convergence is uniform (this is a sufficient but not necessary condition).

Comment: Yes this is right, as is Bungo's reply. On a side note this is pretty much the only definition of the Cantor function I ever learned and it is indeed quite nice, though Wikipedia supports your experience as the norm by listing it as an "alternative definition."

Comment: And on another side note the Cantor function can be defined as a cumulative integral of a certain measure, from which these properties do follow immediately. (If you're familiar with probability, it is a CDF. The distribution it represents is interesting..)

Comment: Do you know where I can read up on this?

Comment: The Wikipedia article mentions this. There is also one on the "Cantor distribution". I also recall seeing a nice answer on math se  regarding singular parts of probability distributions but I don't remember where it is.